# How does PassHasBeenSet honeypot contract work?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, security

I've been trying to pick [this honeypot contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x13c547Ff0888A0A876E6F1304eaeFE9E6E06FC4B#code) apart, but I haven't figured out exactly how it works.

**overview**

The premise is pretty simple, the contract is set up to look like a "new year's gift" where the ETH is retrievable if someone (probably the gift receipient) puts in the correct password.

However the contract author has made a fatal "flaw". If a certain field named `passHasBeenSet` is false, anyone can send the contract >1 ETH and become the contract's owner! Once you're the owner, you can call the `revoce` function to pull out all of the funds in the contract.

What's the problem? I found this contract suspect because it was 1) created by the creator of another honeypot contract described on reddit and 2) generally strange - why post the source to Etherscan? Why allow someone else to become the owner if they pay more into the contract? The contract is designed with if statements/doesn't throw errors and looks like it was written by a beginner.

However, I couldn't initially spot anything wrong with the contract. Additionally, it seemed like it only had two transactions, a contract creation and a call to `setPass`. This *should* still leave `passHasBeenSet` set to false.

**pen testing**

I figured I might as well see if the contract was a Honeypot or not. I knew I could design the "attack" contract so I couldn't lose, but I was still curious.

I put together a contract that would call `setPass` and then `revoce`. If the contract's balance decreased, it would revert. This construction meant I couldn't lose any money.

The honeypot contract (& attacking contract) worked as expected on Ropsten. Any balance in the contract was extracted and could then be withdrawn from then attacking contract. However, [the attacking contract failed](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4785aeb3b79713642555fcf7d94c5b2fc893d567bc3e132e6b6c79fe4f212c84) on the mainnet. The balance was successfully sent to the target contract, but the `revoce` failed so the contract's revert failsafe was triggered. Debugging the transaction showed that `passHasBeenSet` was true.

So, how did the "vulnerable" contract manage to set `passHasBeenSet`? I must be missing something pretty obvious.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to put a comment. > The balance was successfully sent to the target contract If `passHasBeenSet` was true, how did your contract's call to `SetPass(`) succeed in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PassHasBeenSet` was called in this transaction:

https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x17c44511bcb28a34eac5653fc6cdd8367a978265e7528a0660f7e8aa9c8b55e7&type=parity

Look for `0x31fd725a` in the trace. (That's the function selector for `PassHasBeenSet(bytes32)`.)

This trick takes advantage of the fact that Etherscan doesn't show all the calls to a contract. (I believe it skips messages from another contract when no ether is attached.) Etherchain does better: https://www.etherchain.org/account/13c547Ff0888A0A876E6F1304eaeFE9E6E06FC4B#transactions.

Comment: Well, that solves it. That's a really interesting way to take advantage of Etherscan specifically.